# TYPO3 Dynamic assigment of DCE template file

Tags: templates, typo3, typoscript, tx-dce

I created a "Person" DCE, that holds field describing persons in my website. 
I have a file based template to display all the person fields.

On some page I want show only a subset of the fields.

Is it possible to overwrite the dce's file based template path with some typoscript?

thanx in advance,

siepmannj

Answer (score 0):

reading the documentation helps.

As I add the Persons" as childs of a parent dce i have full access to the childs fields in the parents template.

Look here: https://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-dce/wiki/How_to_nest_DCEs

siepmannj